# return Json string not working

Tags: php, json, xml

I want to get data from api.. 
but I have trouble with json ..I can not get json string .. it print as normal string or xml..
I try multi method from net but no solution..
this my code:

```
$url = "http://fv4online.com/egov_api/v1/students/7";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: 
application/json;charset=UTF-8'));

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 

$output = curl_exec($ch); 
print_r($output);

$t=json_decode($output,true);
print_r($t);

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
```

result of print ($output) is string:
    7345345343testtesttesttest2000testliterary4564620171testDamascusar_lang300600350en_lang160400200fr_lang160400200national80200100history120300200geograph120300200philosophy160400300religion802001501700155060successful

and result of print(var_dump($output)) is xml:

'
7345345343testtesttesttest2000testliterary4564620171testDamascusar_lang<'... (length=1544)

---

note: Previously I was able to get this data without any problems, but suddenly the problem arose

Comment: If it worked before, and now doesn't, then that suggests a problem with the server. Talk to the people providing the API to get it resolved.

Comment: And please promise us you never do `print(var_dump($output)) ` again? It's one or the other.

Answer (score -1):

That string contains all values the XML from the url returns, just without the tags around them. If you do 'View Source' you'll see more.

You get XML, not JSON. Could be they've changed that (which would be a bit odd, but I've seen worse). If  you want is as JSON:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$json = json_encode($xml);
```

Comment: If an answer answers your question, please mark them as solution so that other user can easily see what the solution to the question is